# Spring cannot get a hibernate session

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Using Spring 2.0.5

in the dao class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class IsActiveTestDao {
  private EntityManager em;

 public void populateIsActiveTest(){
    Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
```

when I do this or any 50 other ways like:

```
SessionFactory f = em.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
```

I have also tried

```
em.getDelegate()
```

I always get a Null Pointer Exception

My question is Can I obtain a hibernate session from a JPA Entity Manager in Spring while using the @Transactional annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @PersistenceContext annotation to the EntityManager to specify the persistence unit you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an @Autowired annotation to the EntityManager

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a null EntityManager. So, you are getting a null pointer exception
You need to fetch the EntityManager object from Application context either by

```
 @PersistenceContext
```

or

```
 @Autowired
```

to get the initialized object of EntityManager.

Doing this will work for you.